# Django - Upload a valid image

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, django-models

I'm using Ubuntu, Django 1.3, Python 2.7.
When I try to upload certain types of image, I get this message:

> Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.

It's happening with PNG and JPG (the formats that I need).
tiff and gif (that I don't and will never care about) are working.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And don't forget about jpeg-lib! Without it PIL willn't understand with what format it can works.

Comment: Thank you, actually I simply installed PIL and it apparently installed all the needed libraries.

Comment: @Glide this applies only if you use apt/aptitude try with pip and you get no support for jpg/png/... :)

Comment: Did you install it from OS repos or from pyPi? Be careful. If you will try to install PIL from pypi you will get format-error. :)

Answer (score 4):

Install PIL !

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-imaging
```

(for Ubuntu or other Debian distrib)

Answer (score 2):

If you get this error and you've PIL installed on Ubuntu check that you've jpeg, freetype, zlib libraries installed.

I suggest you also to use apt/aptitude rather than pip/easy_install.

If you really want to install PIL with pip please notice that the PIL setup will not find your installed libraries (libjpg ...) because Ubuntu installs those libs

here -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu for 64bit 
or 
here -> /usr/lib/x86_32-linux-gnu for 32bit

to fix this you can add this to the setup.py (of course you need to download a copy of PIL from here -> http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

around line 200 (you should see other paths around there)

```
add_directory(library_dirs, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this error can be caused by IntegrityError while saving to db